# PHP mysql subqueries filtering

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table like this:

```
id     price    condition     username
----------------------------------------
 1       20     New           Kim 
 2       30     Used          Kim
 3       40     Used          George
 4       60     New           Tom
```

My question is about subselection. when I use this query,

```
SELECT *
FROM `table`
WHERE `username` = 'kim'
  AND `price` = '20'
   OR `condition` = 'New'
```

it becomes true for the last condition and brings 2 records where condition = 'New'

However, when I use AND, it returns the correct record.

```
SELECT *
FROM `table`
WHERE `username` = 'kim'
  AND `price` = '20'
  AND `condition` = 'New'
```

I want to nest the query such that I can select price and condition only from the results of the first query, which is username. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE username = 'kim' AND (price = '20' OR condition = 'New');
```

Answer (score 2):

As Rafal Wojcik said you need to utilize some parenthesis to tell the database what OR you're grouping.

Without any guidence the engine groups all your conditionals as they come:

```
username = 'kim' AND price = 20 OR condition = 'New'
```

reads as

```
((username = 'kim' AND price = 20) OR condition = 'New')
```

As you see this is not what you wanted. Here OR applies to "kim-20" OR "New"

Same issue is observed with your all `AND` case.

Good luck!